# Ползунок на js с шагом 0.1

Tags: javascript

У меня имеется ползунок на js:

```
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0.2" max="3" value="" class="slider" id="myRange">
    <p>Значение: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; 


slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

Сейчас ползунок двигается с шагом 1, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы он двигался с шагом 0.1? На форумах ничего внятного не нашел(

Comment: делите значение на 10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Разобрался! Необходимо прописать значение step:

```
<input type="range" min="0.2" max="3" value="" class="slider" id="myRange" step="0.1
```